# Is there a way to pass three variable in one foreach controller in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Have following three list of variable,

```
uuid_list = [
1.2.840.113619.2.340.3.1690305638.390.1427901609.859.121.0,
1.2.840.113619.2.340.3.1690305638.390.1427901609.859.121.1,
1.2.840.113619.2.340.3.1690305638.390.1427901609.859.121.2,
1.2.840.113619.2.340.3.1690305638.390.1427901609.859.121.3,
1.2.840.113619.2.340.3.1690305638.390.1427901609.859.121.4,
1.2.840.113619.2.340.3.1690305638.390.1427901609.859.121.5,
1.2.840.113619.2.340.3.1690305638.390.1427901609.859.121.6,
1.2.840.113619.2.340.3.1690305638.390.1427901609.859.121.7,
1.2.840.113619.2.340.3.1690305638.390.1427901609.859.121.8,
1.2.840.113619.2.340.3.1690305638.390.1427901609.859.121.9]

file_list = [
555210_98168_98980_0.img,
555210_98168_98980_1.img,
555210_98168_98980_2.img,
555210_98168_98980_3.img,
555210_98168_98980_4.img,
555210_98168_98980_5.img,
555210_98168_98980_6.img,
555210_98168_98980_7.img,
555210_98168_98980_8.img,
555210_98168_98980_9.img]

file_path = [
C:\PerformanceTestFiles\555210_98168_98980_0.img, 
C:\PerformanceTestFiles\555210_98168_98980_1.img, 
C:\PerformanceTestFiles\555210_98168_98980_2.img, 
C:\PerformanceTestFiles\555210_98168_98980_3.img, 
C:\PerformanceTestFiles\555210_98168_98980_4.img, 
C:\PerformanceTestFiles\555210_98168_98980_5.img, 
C:\PerformanceTestFiles\555210_98168_98980_6.img, 
C:\PerformanceTestFiles\555210_98168_98980_7.img, 
C:\PerformanceTestFiles\555210_98168_98980_8.img, 
C:\PerformanceTestFiles\555210_98168_98980_9.img]
```

Can I use them in foreach controller? like as follow

- Input variable prefix: uuid_list,file_list,file_path
- Output variable name : uuid_list,file_list,file_path

to my next http call which I want to iterate. I am obtaining them from my previous `JSR223-postprocesser`. I cannot use any external data source as well.

Note: The size of the three list will be always equal, like in my case it is 10 in the above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot do it using ForEach Controller, but there is a work around using `__V()` and `__counter()` function combination.

Let continue from the value,
from the main `post-processor`, put these object

```
vars.putObject("imageUIDListVal", uuid_list);
vars.putObject("fileListVal", file_list);
vars.putObject("filePathListVal", file_path);
```

next `post-processor`,

```
def imgUIDArrayList = vars.getObject("imageUIDListVal");
def fileListArrayList = vars.getObject("fileListVal");
def filePathListArrayList = vars.getObject("filePathListVal");

1.upto(imgUIDArrayList.size(),{ vars.put('imageUUIDA_' + it, imgUIDArrayList.get(it - 1))})

1.upto(fileListArrayList.size(), { vars.put('fileUUIDA_' + it, fileListArrayList.get(it - 1))})

1.upto(filePathListArrayList.size(), { vars.put('filePathUUIDA_' + it, filePathListArrayList.get(it - 1))})
```

now in the `for-each controller` just sent one value, I used your `imageUUIDA`

[image]

Now you can use,

`${imageUUIDA} - ${__V(fileUUIDA_${__counter(,)})} - ${__V(filePathUUIDA_${__counter(,)})}` for iterating .

[image]

Details of these two functions are here, [v_function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [counter_function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter)