# How to iterate request using parallel / throughput controller in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Continuing from my previous question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76692473/is-there-a-way-to-pass-three-variable-in-one-foreach-controller-in-jmeter/76692642#76692642).

It is working fine with  small value of these three parameter which I am receiving from previous post-processer,

```
def imgUIDArrayList = vars.getObject("imageUIDListVal");
def fileListArrayList = vars.getObject("fileListVal");
def filePathListArrayList = vars.getObject("filePathListVal");

1.upto(imgUIDArrayList.size(),{ vars.put('imageUUIDA_' + it, imgUIDArrayList.get(it - 1))})
1.upto(fileListArrayList.size(), { vars.put('fileUUIDA_' + it, fileListArrayList.get(it - 1))})
1.upto(filePathListArrayList.size(), { vars.put('filePathUUIDA_' + it, filePathListArrayList.get(it - 1))})
```

for example the value's size is 10(which is lesser in number) working fine and emulate like the real api. But when the size is increasing like more than 100 sometime more than 1000. The execution time for JMeter is very high like more than 30min sometime close to hour. And for 1 user and it grows with concurrency, but not seeing similar behavior while using api. I have not set any timer for my transaction.

Thinking of using parallel controller or throughput controller. In such case how I can use these 3 value to iterate for the number of times equals to number of size ? Or any better option ?

Current configuration in `for-each` controller,

[image]

and inside the controller I am using other two variable by calling ,

`${__V(fileUUIDA_${__counter(,)})}` and `vars.get('filePathUUIDA_' + ((vars.get('__jm__ForEach Controller__idx') as int) + 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) executes its children in parallel which means that you need to define the relevant [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) beforehand.

If your requests are simple GET requests you can consider switching to the [Parallel Sampler](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampler), you can create/add URLs dynamically using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the code like:

```
0.upto(vars.getObject('imageUIDListVal').size() - 1, index -> {
    sampler.addURL('your-url-prefix-' + imageUIDListVal[index])
})
```

More information: [How to Use the Parallel Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/parallel-controller-in-jmeter)

Also you shouldn't be sending requests "fast", you should exactly replicate the network footprint of the real user (or upstream system) so it worth double-checking your requirements. Maybe it worth writing the payloads to CSV file and use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and multiple threads for executing the requests.